# JQuery modal doesn't get popuped

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, dialog

I want to display a popup box. I tried it in this way.

In the Layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
});
</script>
```

And in my index view

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic Modal Dailog">
   <p>Successfully Updated</p>
</div>
```

But this only shows the text in index view("Successfully Updated") without showing a dialogbox. The dialog box is not working. What might cause this? pls help!
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, thanks for replying. No errors in console. It just doesn't work. No dialog box gets opened. Just shows the text.

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, sorry, yes there is an error. give me a min to put it here

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, This is the error.                                              "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function"

Comment: is the jquery file included in the layout?

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, Yes, I included above jquery files in layout

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, are there any other files to be included?

Comment: can you check the source code to see if jquery file is added?

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, ok pls give me a min. i'll check for it

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan, pls tell me what specific jquery file you are mentioning here. i have only included two files.

Comment: can you look at this question. might be related. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25504528/1479535

Comment: Your `$('#dialog-modal').dialog({` script should be in the view, not the layout. And do you have any `@Scripts.Render()` or `<script src="..` in the view?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, hey thanks :) Ok I'll get the script in to view. No, all the @Scripts.Render() and <script src="..  are in layout. i'll get them in to the view. I'll tell you the result in 5 min.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, I got the script and other jquery files im calling in to the index view. But still not working. The source is showing me this same error.  "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function". What might be the problem?

Comment: Note the `@Scripts.Render()` and `<script src=".. ` can still be in the layout (so that they can be used by multiple views. It was only the function I was referring to (because that's specific to your view). The error your getting suggests your `jquery-ui` script is not being loaded.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, Ok i got that point. The Source shows me all the files i included. There is another warning as well. "'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach)". I've added these files of juery. 'jquery-1.10.2.js' and 'jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js'  and a css file 'jquery-ui.css'. do these files get conflicted because of the different versions? and is it necessary to include these files if im rendering '@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")' and '*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")'?

Comment: @Isuru, `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` will include `jquery-{some version}.js` so you should not be adding it again by including `jquery-1.10.2.js`. As for `Range.detach' is now a no-op` that seems unrelated to the code you have shown - are you using any other plugins? (I know it was an issue with `Rangy`)

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, In Jquery bundle it is version 1.10.2. So i removed jquery-1.10.2.min.js which added by myself and then removed jquery-ui.css as  well. But still not working. I am trying this on a fresh mvc project. So i suppose no other plugins. Earlier i tried this on my original project. But it was same like this. But with extra errors like 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' So i tried it on a fresh mvc project. 'Range' warning and the 'uncaught type error' were same in these 2 projects. Do i have to add something to visual studio?

Comment: Where is renderBody method in _layout.cshtml ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog({ modal: true,

                })

        </script>
    }

    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Successully Updated">

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Yes your code is correct. But the issue was due to the different versions of jquery in my project. I had to avoid rendering jquery bundle and to keep a unique version of Jquery.js, Jquery-ui.js and Jquery-ui.css in my view.

Comment: now , if you can add and link your project to the css style and latest Jquery file js jQuery 1.11.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

  <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    </script>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Successfully Updated"></div>
```